# SQL Server Table > MS Access Local Copy?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I'm looking for a little advice.

I have some SQL Server tables I need to move to local Access databases for some local production tasks - once per "job" setup, w/400 jobs this qtr, across a dozen users...

A little background:

1. I am currently using a DSN-less approach to avoid distribution issues
2. I can create temporary LINKS to the remote tables and run "make table" queries to populate the local tables, then drop the remote tables.  Works as expected.
3. Performance here in US is decent - 10-15 seconds for ~40K records.  Our India teams are seeing >5-10 minutes for the same datasets.  Their internet connection is decent, not great and a variable I cannot control.
4. I am wondering if MS Access is adding some overhead here than can be avoided by a more direct approach:  i.e., letting the server do all/most of the heavy lifting vs Access?

I've tinkered with various combinations, with no clear improvement or success:

- Parameterized stored procedures from Access
- SQL Passthru queries from Access
- ADO vs DAO

Any suggestions, or an overall approach to suggest?  How about moving data as XML?

Note:  I have Access 7, 10, 13 users.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to use Access? What about SQL Server Compact or Express, or a number of others?

Comment: Have you considered SQL express locally?

Comment: Access is necessary.  Some historical elements here (forms and such).  New ENV just not feasible at the moment.

Comment: How about have the people in India remote into a computer physically located in your location to run Access locally?

Comment: Is using Access' Synchronization an option?  I did that with an old company where we had 2 offices, and I set it up to sync every 10 minutes.  Worked like a charm.  This way India can have their own local copy and not need to dial into yours.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear but if the MSAccess database performing the dump is local and the SQL Server database is remote, across the internet, you are bound to bump into the physical limitations of the connection.

ODBC drivers are not meant to be used for data access beyond a LAN, there is too much latency.
When Access queries data, is doesn't open a stream, it fetches blocks of it, wait for the data wot be downloaded, then request another batch. This is OK on a LAN but quickly degrades over long distances, especially when you consider that communication between the US and India has probably around 200ms latency and you can't do much about it as it adds up very quickly if the communication protocol is chatty, all this on top of the connection's bandwidth that is very likely way below what you would get on a LAN.

The better solution would be to perform the dump locally and then transmit the resulting Access file after it has been compacted and maybe zipped (using 7z for instance for better compression). This would most likely result in very small files that would be easy to move around in a few seconds.

The process could easily be automated. The easiest is maybe to automatically perform this dump every day and making it available on an FTP server or an internal website ready for download.

You can also make it available on demand, maybe trough an app running on a server and made available through RemoteApp using RDP services on a Windows 2008 server or simply though a website, or a shell.
You could also have a simple windows service on your SQL Server that listens to requests for a remote client installed on the local machines everywhere, that would process the dump and sent it to the client which would then unpack it and replace the previously downloaded database.

Plenty of solutions for this, even though they would probably require some amount of work to automate reliably.

One final note: if you automate the data dump from SQL Server to Access, avoid using Access in an automated way. It's hard to debug and quite easy to break. Use an export tool instead that doesn't rely on having Access installed.

Answer (score 0):

Renaud and all, thanks for taking time to provide your responses.  As you note, performance across the internet is the bottleneck.  The fetching of blocks (vs a continguous DL) of data is exactly what I was hoping to avoid via an alternate approach.

Or workflow is evolving to better leverage both sides of the clock where User1 in US completes their day's efforts in the local DB and then sends JUST their updates back to the server (based on timestamps).  User2 in India, also has a local copy of the same DB, grabs just the updated records off the server at the start of his day.  So, pretty efficient for day-to-day stuff.

The primary issue is the initial DL of the local DB tables from the server (huge multi-year DB) for the current "job" - should happen just once at the start of the effort (~1 wk long process)  This is the piece that takes 5-10 minutes for India to accomplish.

We currently do move the DB back and forth via FTP - DAILY.  It is used as a SINGLE shared DB and is a bit LARGE due to temp tables.  I was hoping my new timestamped-based push-pull of just the changes daily would have been an overall plus.  Seems to be, but the initial DL hurdle remains.